# Convert string containg base64 to valid base64String

Tags: c#, base64

I'm having a string, `string myImgSrc` containg "base64".

The string starts with:
`data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4QAYRXhpZgAASUkqAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAP/....`

I know it is valid base64 because it will render as a image if a put it in a `<img src="HERE" />`

But how do I convert this type of base64 string to a "real" base64String?

I need it as "real" base64 when uploading though a API

With "real" base64 I mean something looking like this: [base64 here](http://pastebin.com/bfc1E1NV)

Comment: Just chop off everything before and including the comma?

Answer (score 0):

One way is to remove the start of your base64 string using replace.

**VB**

```
Dim Base64 As String = myImgSrc
Dim Code = Base64 .Replace("data:image/jpeg;base64,", "")
```

**OUTPUT**

```
data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4QAYRXhpZgAASUkqAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAP/....
```

Will become:

```
/9j/4QAYRXhpZgAASUkqAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAP/....
```